# Among all collections, X, of positive integers whose sum is 28, what is the largest product that the integers in X can form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Among all collections, X, of positive integers whose sum is 28, what is the largest product that the integers in X can form

**My approach:-**

I am not able to come up with some well organized approach , started with some random checks like if I use 14 times 2 , I end up with product $2^{14}$, if I break it in 14,14 the value becomes much lesser $14^2$ , but checking like this would be too much cumbersome, what would be a nice organized and efficient manner to tackle this problem

Comment: Note that $3^9>2^{14}$, but even $3^9$ is not maximal.

Comment: Also $4\cdot 3^8 > 2^{14}$.

Comment: Some observations that might help:  there is no reason to have, say, a $5$ in your final result.  After all $5=2+3$ and $2\times 3>5$.  Indeed, there is no reason to consider any number $>5$.  Similarly, there is no advantage in having a $4$.  Thus you only have to worry about $\{1,2,3\}$ and of course you should never have more than one $1$.

Comment: Nor should you have three $2's$ since $2+2+2=6=3+3$ and $3\times 3>2\times 2\times 2$.  So, really, there's not a lot of cases to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

For any $n$, not just $28$, consider an optimal partition.  Clearly, that partition can not contain any integer $k≥5$ since $k=(k-2)+2$ and $$(k-2)\times 2=2k-4>k$$.

Similarly, there is no reason to include a $4$ since we can replace $4$ by $2,2$ without changing the produce.

It follows that there is an optimal partition consisting only of $1's,2's,3's$.

Now, the optimal partition can not have two $1's$, clearly.

Similarly, it can not have three $2's$, since $2+2+2=3+3$ and $3^2>2^3$.

Thus we only need to consider partitions with no $2's$ or with one or two $2's$.

In the present example, that means that we only need to  consider the partitions:  $$\{3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1\}\quad \&\quad \{3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2\}$$ and the second one wins.

This procedure generalizes quite easily.

As @TonyK points out in the comments, for $n>1$, there is no reason to have a $1$ in the optimal partition.  $\{1,2\}$ should be replaced by $3$, and $\{1,3\}$ should be replaced by $\{2,2\}$.  Hence, for any $n$, there is only one partition to consider, and the form just depends on $n\pmod 3$.

Comment: $1,1$ can be replaced by $2$; $2,1$ can be replaced by $3$; and $3,1$ can be replaced by $2,2$. So $1$ is never useful (assuming $n>1$).

Comment: @TonyK  Good point.  So the optimal partition can be read off, and the form only depends on knowing $n\pmod 3$.

Comment: @lulu can you please explain why are we not considering any number >=5 , I am not able to understand the reason for rejecting these values

Comment: I gave an explanation in the post. If $k≥5$ then you can replace $k$ with the pair $(k-2,2)$.  That pair still sums to $k$ but the product $2k-4$ is bigger than $k$.  Similarly, with $k=4$ you can replace $4$ with $(2,2)$ without changing the product.

Comment: ...thus, no optimal partition can contain any integer greater than $4$, and while there might or might not be optimal partitions which contain $4$, there is always one that has no $4's$ in it.